# Does perpendicular to the plane mean perpendicular to the normal?

Tags: geometry

So if a plane is perpendicular to a line is the line perpendicular to its normal or is it perpendicular to,you know, its surface?

Comment: If a plane is perpendicular to a line, the normal of the plane must be parallel to that line.

Comment: To its 'surface', it (i.e. the line) would then be parallel to a normal of the plane.

Comment: The legs of a table are perpendicular to its surface, and vice versa

Answer (score 4):

> The normal vector, often simply called the "normal," to a surface is a vector which is perpendicular to the surface at a given point.

Hence, the [normal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) of a plane is perpendicular to that given plane. Consider this image for illustration:

[image]

As can be seen in the picture, the normal is perpendicular to the plane, and any other vector that passes through the plane at a right-angle $(90^o)$ is parallel to the normal. This is equivalent to sliding the normal to any position on the plane without changing its angles.

In short,

- **perpendicular to plane $\enspace \Longleftrightarrow \enspace$ parallel or incident to normal**.
- **perpendicular to normal $\enspace \Longleftrightarrow \enspace$ parallel or incident to plane**

Comment: Yes. I have added it. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I must not have read your previous comment properly. I will add the reverse relation as well (ie. you are referring to the "perpendicular to normal iff parallel or incident to plane" relation right)